# How to create a bottom left triangle with biggest side oval rounded and use it to shape a square image?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create an almost oval shaped image with CSS exactly like the following image:

[image]

I suppose I have to first create a bottom left triangle and then add another oval shaped div on top of it with the square image/picture to shape it.

I can't use js or SVG, only HTML, and CSS.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, im not seeking debug, i don't really know how to do it. The desired effect is in the first image.

Comment: thanks @j08691, will not post again.

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  height: 500px;
  width:500px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000?image=1069) center/cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(65% 86% at 66% 1%);
  clip-path: ellipse(65% 86% at 66% 1%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: that looks pretty good. thanks that's exactly what i was looking for.